# ASP.Net Session_Start event not firing

Tags: asp.net, iis, session, global-asax

I have an ASP.Net 2.0 application in which the Session_Start event is not firing in my Global.asax file. Can anyone tell why this is happening and how I can get it working?

The application worked fine on my Windows XP development machine, but stopped working when deployed to the server (Win Server 2003/IIS 6/ASP.Net 2.0).

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but the server also hosts a SharePoint installation (WSS 3.0) which I know does change some settings at the default web site level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the site precompiled before adding global.asax? Try compiling it again.

Comment: The entire site has been compiled and recompiled several times, I can step into other code that is in the Global.asax file e.g. Application_Start()

Comment: can you create a copy of the site and see if the problem occurs on the copy as well?

Comment: Whilst not quite answering the question, the point about whether or not the site was precompiled was just the hint I needed to solve the problem, which was a missing PrecompiledApp.config file on the production server. Thanks @Gulzar

Answer (score 1):

Is the `<session />` section in the web.config?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the website in IIS is set to use ASP.NET 2.0 rather than 1.1?

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the following tag in SharePoint 2010 web.config:

< remove name="Session" />